# How to use only hover or only focus in SCSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my `Vue` input component. This component has such styles:

```css
.basic-input:hover { box-shadow: 0 0 5px $maincolor; }
.basic-input:focus { border: 0.5px solid $maincolor; }
```

As you can see it has box shadow on hover and border on focus. Here is the problem, if I have focus and hover at the same time, I has box shadow **and** border.

I want to make it work like this - if it's hover or focus, it has to be like it is, but If it has focus **and** hover at the same time, I want to use only border. I was trying to do this like that, but it doesn't work:

```css
.basic-input:focus .basic-input:hover { border: 0.5px solid $maincolor; }
```

Comment: You should be using `:focus-visible` instead of `:focus` now. And (generally speaking) the `:focus`/`:focus-visible` pseudo-classes should only set `outline` or `box-shadow`, not `border` (because changing `border` affects layout, whereas `outline` and `box-shadow` do not).

Comment: `0.5px` <-- How do you expect this to render on a 96dpi display?

Comment: instead of the `.basic-input:focus .basic-input:hover` selector, which is a `.basic-input` *within* another `.basic-input` (the space selects children) you want `.basic-input:focus:hover`

Comment: @Lux I was trying to do this, and it doesn't work